# Publishing doesn't update the partial [ C#/MVC/ASP.Net ]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

Visual Studio seems to no longer want to publish changes for files to our local IIS server, this only happens for partial files, but then again only for some.

- I've tried running iisreset in cmd as administrator
- I've tried cleaning the solution, and publishing
- I've tried deleting the **bin** and **obj** folders
- I've tried recycling the pool and restarting the site in iis
- I've tried hard refreshing and flushing the cache on chrome

I'm at an end for what to do, is there anything that i might have missed?

Thanks

Comment: I have had a similar issue that was due to Windows Update. There was an update to the web deploy service and it was holding any changes up. This is going to sound so cliche IT crowd, but did you try restarting the server?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i've not got any pending windows updates and yes i've restarted the server and still nothing

Comment: Are you in a position where you can restart the server a few times and not bother users? I would try to manually delete the project deployment file in your visual studio with File Explorer and try it again. If that doesn't work, nuke Web Deploy on the server and reinstall it. It is really a fickle solution, but when it works its awesome.

Comment: A mixture of nuking web deploy and deleting everything seems to have resolved the issue. It seems doing this has somehow allowed a "failed to find partial in directory" IIS error page to appear that wasn't there earlier. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mixture of nuking web deploy and deleting everything seems to have resolved the issue. It seems doing this has somehow allowed a "failed to find partial in directory" IIS error page to appear that wasn't there earlier.